# Add null columns np array when new phrase comes

Tags: python, numpy

Im training a model to detect entities in phrases.
My train is composed by 500 phrases, which have 1000 words. So, my

```
X_train.shape = (500,1000) 

X_train = [[0. 0. 0. 0. ...], [0. 0. ...], ...]. <-- already have this
```

**Each column is about an specific word (order is very important).**

When I want to predict a new phrase's entity, I can receive words never seen.
Consider that I receive the input: "My shirt is yellow"

I need to put this input in form of an np.array with shape (1, 1000). If the word yellow doesn't exists, I need to have an shape (1,1001) and retrain the model (with all zeros for that column, ofc). How can I do this?

Small example:

```
           "I" "am" "dark" "Vader's" "son". (trained corpus)
X_train = [[1,   1,   0,      0,      0], 
           [1,   1,   1,      0,      0]]
```

New input: Predict "I am dark Vader's daughter"

So I need to retrain my model with:

```
       "I" "am" "dark" "Vader's" "son" "daughter". (trained corpus)
X_train = [[1,   1,   0,      0,      0,   0], 
           [1,   1,   1,      0,      0,   0]]
```

So I can predict the new input:

`X_predict = [[1,1,1,1,0,1]]` - also need to put this in this form

Answer (score 0):

You coul use [`np.append`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.append.html) and [`np.zeros`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.zeros.html):

```
X_train = np.append(X_train, np.zeros((X_train.shape[0], 1)), axis=1)
print(X_train)
```

**Output**

```
array([[1., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [1., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0.]])
```